# NFC wont send URL to mobile phone

Tags: i2c

I'm using  nfc 2 click (NT3H2111), I tried via arduino to send data to my mobile phone using this code :

```
#include <Wire.h>

int i = 0;
int j = 0;




uint8_t NDEF_DATA[] = { 0x03, // NDEF Message
15, // Message size
0xD1, // Record header
1, // Type Length - 1 byte
11, // Payload Length - 11 bytes
'U', // Type / URI
0x01, // Payload
'm', 'i', 'k', 'r', 'o', 'e', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm',
0xFE
}; // NDEF Message End Mark


void setup()
{

delay(5000);
Wire.begin();
// initialisation de la liaison I2C
Serial.begin(9600);
// initialisation de la liaison série vers la console

Wipe_Tag() ;

Wire.beginTransmission(0x55);
Wire.write(0x00);
Wire.endTransmission();
Wire.requestFrom(0x55, 7);
Serial.println("UUID:");
while(Wire.available())
{
Serial.print(Wire.read(),HEX);
}

delay(1000);
Serial.println();

Serial.println("Start wrting");
Wire.beginTransmission(0x55);
Wire.write(0x01);

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
Wire.write(NDEF_DATA[i]); //Fill Block with Data
}
Wire.endTransmission();
delay(50);

Wire.beginTransmission(0x55);
Wire.write(0x02);

for (i = 16; i < 32; i++)
{
Wire.write(NDEF_DATA[i]); //Fill Block with Data
}
Wire.endTransmission();
delay(50);

Serial.println("Start wrting");

}
void loop()
{

}

void Wipe_Tag()
{
for (i = 1; i < 50; i++)
{
Wire.beginTransmission(0x55);
Wire.write(i);
for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
{
Wire.write(0x00); //Fill Block with Zeros
}
Wire.endTransmission();
delay(50); //Delay 50 ms

}
}
```

All I get is the right UUID than nothing happened, if I try to put my phone I can't read nothing ( it should send me to mikroe website).

As I'm using the nfc 2 click from mikroe.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't know, wild shot in the dark, but which of the fields count towards the message size parameter, but you might want to check it has the right value. 
Also do you need a null at the end of the text?

Comment: Also, in the loops you are sending 16 bytes, but the NEF_DATA contains 18 bytes.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your help, in fact each register has 16 bits, this is why I divided the data into two registers